# Android getIntent() returns same intent in onResume() each time. how to clear int field in a bundle?

Tags: android

I am working on app that uses getIntent() to read bundled information.  I would like to set one of the bundle fields to null, so that on subsequent resumes a modified intent is received, but I keep getting the same intent back from getIntent().  I notice that after the back key is pressed than a new intent is produced, but not otherwise.

```
 intent.getExtras().getInt("FLAG_FIELD") returns 1
 intent.getExtras().setString("FLAG_FIELD", null);
```

but when the Activity resumes again getInt() still returns a value instead of null. Not sure than how to clear a Int field in a bundle.

Update just tried:

```
intent.getExtras().putInt("FLAG_FIELD, -1);
```

This also does not work. Looks like intent from getIntent() cannot be changed.

Update:  onResume() gets called in the debugger 3 times in a row before the activity becomes visible? So even if I set a flag here it seems that its hard to change state because I cannot tell which resume() call is the last one before an actual display.

Comment: Can you post the functions that use this so we have some context?

Comment: I'm a bit confused but you need to change the value when you use `intent.putExtra()` then it will be changed the next time you get the intent

Comment: Well the only thing to add is that I am checkin getIntent() field in onResume() and then clearing the flag still in onResume. The real question is can you change bundle for getIntent() or is it unchangable?  looks like it is unchangeable.

Comment: Is it actually going into the method or the debugger goes to the method signature and moves on but doesn't enter the method?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can override `onNewIntent()` and change the extras there.
[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) is the documentation for that. After this method, your `onResume()` will be called which I think is what you are after

Comment: Ok. The other issue is that I am seeing that onResume seems to be called several times. So for example turning on/off a flag does not wok because it of the multiple times it executes.

Comment: Without seeing more of the code I can't tell you much but I can tell you that onResume() will be called after the activity starts per the [Android Activity LifeCycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) You will have to override it and put in code to deal with the data however you need to...maybe a counter, some flag,etc. its hard to say without knowing what you have going on

Comment: thanks. I found that the additional call was not from onResume getting called excessively but other parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my problem was an error with selected intent flags.
My not working code was:

```
notificationIntent.setFlags((Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));
```

Now I solved with

```
 notificationIntent.setFlags((PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Yeah, not the best solution, but it works